# XML to XML , unable to use copy of select with Repeated element

Tags: xslt-2.0

We need to perform XML to XML transformation, in expected output we need to have exact same input XML , but will need store WE value in variable , so that we can apply EDM and replace the value in the same place.
Please guide on the same.

XSLT:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result- 
  prefixes="#all" >

<xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="bap/tables/table"/>

</xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

INPUT -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bap name="ABC">
   <tables>
  <table name="IT">
     <row id="0">
        <field name="FIL">2019</field>
        <field name="WE">000A</field>
        <field name="CON" />
     </row>
     <row id="1">
        <field name="FIL">2019</field>
        <field name="WE">000B</field>
        <field name="CONTROL" />
     </row>
     <row id="2">
        <field name="FIL">2019</field>
        <field name="WE">000C</field>
        <field name="CON" />
     </row>
  </table>
   </tables>
 </bap>
```

OUTPUT:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bap name="ABC">
<tables>
    <table name="IT">
        <row id="0">
            <field name="FIL">2019</field>
            <field name="WE">0987</field> - value should be replaceable 
            <field name="CON" />
        </row>
        <row id="1">
            <field name="FIL">2019</field>
            <field name="WE">98I8</field>
            <field name="CONTROL" />
        </row>
        <row id="2">
            <field name="FIL">2019</field>
            <field name="WE">76y5</field>
            <field name="CON" />
        </row>
    </table>
</tables>
```

Comment: What would look like your desired output?

Comment: @zx485 - The desired output is same as input, only thing is we need to have WE filed name to be stored in variable so that we can apply EDM and replace the value at same place.

Comment: @kuhujain, Are you somehow implying that you need to continue processing **after** the output is produced? It is difficult to understand what do you mean by "The desired output is same as input, only thing is we need to have WE filed name to be stored in variable" -- because the output is produced as result of the transformation -- that is when the transformation has finished and then no variables are available -- only the output

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - I ave updated the Desired output, during copy of select only thing to have WE field to be stored in variable so that we can replace.